# How to save auth-token in Jetpack Datastore and use it in Ktor http-client header

Tags: http-headers, kotlin-coroutines, ktor-client, android-jetpack-datastore

1. I'm developing a sample application for learning Ktor and Datastore
2. First I call login API and get a ticket and it saves in Datastore. These work as expected. For this API call, I'm using another Http-client instance without headers.
3. Next I need to get that ticket from DataStoreManager and set it to the AuthHttpClient header to call other APIs

What's the best approach to this step 3?

AuthHttpClient.kt

```
class AuthHttpClient @Inject constructor(private val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager) {

    fun getHttpClient() = HttpClient(Android) {

        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.DEFAULT
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }

        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            })
        }

        install(DefaultRequest) {
            header("ticket", "YOUR_TICKET")
        }
    }
}
```

DataStoreManager.kt

```
class DataStoreManager @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) {
    private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "app_data")

    val getTicketFlow: Flow<String> = context.dataStore.data.catch {
        when (it) {
            is IOException -> {
                emit(emptyPreferences())
            }
            else -> {
                throw Exception()
            }
        }
    }.map { preferences ->
        preferences[PreferenceKeys.TICKET] ?: ""
    }

    suspend fun updateTicket(ticket: String) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[PreferenceKeys.TICKET] = ticket
        }
    }
}
```